# Ошибка error C2039: {ctor}: не является членом

Tags: c++

Дано: число N и последовательность a1, a2, … aN

Создать шаблон класса, порождающий динамические одномерные массивы с элементами различных типов (вещественные, целочисленные, символьные и т.д.). Тип данных и результат являются параметрами по отношению к классу, программа должна иметь методы инициализации, конструктор, деструктор, метод просмотра значений созданного массива, согласно заданному алгоритму.

```
(a1*a1), (a1*a2), …, (a1*aN);
```

Код

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class Mas
{  
   private:
       T N;
       T* mas;
   public:
       void set(T N);
       void print();
};
template <typename T>
Mas<T>::Mas(T N)
{
    mas = new T [N];
    for(int i(0);i<=N;i++)
    {   
        cin>>mas[i];

    }

}
template <typename T>
Mas<T>::~Mas()
{
    delete [] mas;

}

template <typename T>
 Mas<T>::Mas()
{}

template <typename T>
void Mas<T>::set(T N)
{

    mas = new T [N];
    for(int i(0);i<=N;i++)
    {   
        cin>>mas[i];

    }

};

template <typename T>
void Mas<T>::print()
{
    for(int i(0);i<=N;i++)
 {   
    cout<<mas[i] = mas[1]*mas[i];

    }

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Mas<int> a;
    a.set(3);
    a.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Выдает ошибки:

> ```
>     Ошибка    1   error C2039: {ctor}: не является членом
> ```
>
> "Mas<T>"  c:\users\user\desktop\dz 6\dz
> 6\dz 6.cpp    33  1   DZ 6
>
> ```
> Ошибка    2   error C2039: {dtor}: не является членом
> ```
>
> "Mas<T>"  c:\users\user\desktop\dz 6\dz
> 6\dz 6.cpp    40  1   DZ 6
>
> ```
> Ошибка    3   error C2039: {ctor}: не является членом
> ```
>
> "Mas<T>"  c:\users\user\desktop\dz 6\dz
> 6\dz 6.cpp    44  1   DZ 6

**Как избавится от ошибок, и правильно ли я решил задачу?**

Comment: @MeWn, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Исправил пачку ошибок, читайте комментарии в коде.
Оно теперь компилируется, вроде что-то делает. Правильно или нет, не знаю, я не Ваш учитель.

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class Mas
{  
   private:
       T N;
       T* mas;
   public:
       void set(T N);
       void print();
       Mas(T N); // нужно объявлять конструкторы и деструкторы
       Mas();
       ~Mas();
};
template <typename T>
Mas<T>::Mas(T N)
{
    mas = new T [N];
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) // в оригинальной записи есть выход за пределы
    {   
        cin>>mas[i];
    }
}
template <typename T>
Mas<T>::~Mas()
{
    delete [] mas;
}

template <typename T>
 Mas<T>::Mas()
{}

template <typename T>
void Mas<T>::set(T N)
{
    // эта функция может быть причиной утечек. Представьте, что ее вызвали дважды в коде
    mas = new T [N];
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {   
        cin>>mas[i];

    }

};

template <typename T>
void Mas<T>::print()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {   
    //cout<<mas[i] = mas[1]*mas[i]; тут бред написан.
    // если это печать, то почему она пытается изменять элементы массива?
    // может просто вывести элементы?
    cout << mas[i] << " ";
    }

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Mas<int> a;
    a.set(3);
    a.print();

    return 0;
}
```